# How do I get a list of all parent tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
<folder name="folder1">
     <folder name="folder2">
          <bookmark href="link.html">
     </folder>
</folder>
```

If I point to bookmark, what would be the command to just extract all of the folder lines?
For example,

```
bookmarks = soup.findAll('bookmark')
```

then `beautifulsoupcommand(bookmarks[0])` would return:

```
[<folder name="folder1">,<folder name="folder2">]
```

I'd also want to know when the ending tags hit too. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my stab at it:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<folder name="folder1">
     <folder name="folder2">
          <bookmark href="link.html">
     </folder>
</folder>
"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> bookmarks = soup.find_all('bookmark')
>>> [p.get('name') for p in bookmarks[0].find_all_previous(name = 'folder')]
[u'folder2', u'folder1']
```

The key difference from @eumiro's answer is that I am using `find_all_previous` instead of `find_parents`. When I tested @eumiro's solution I found that `find_parents` only returns the first (immediate) parent as the name of the parent and grandparent are the same.

```
>>> [p.get('name') for p in bookmarks[0].find_parents('folder')]
[u'folder2']

>>> [p.get('name') for p in bookmarks[0].find_parents()]
[u'folder2', None]
```

It does return two generations of parents if the parent and grandparent are differently named.

```
>>> html = """<folder name="folder1">
     <folder_parent name="folder2">
          <bookmark href="link.html">
     </folder_parent>
</folder>
"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> bookmarks = soup.find_all('bookmark')
>>> [p.get('name') for p in bookmarks[0].find_parents()]
[u'folder2', u'folder1', None]
```

Answer (score 2):

`bookmarks[0].findParents('folder')` will return you a list of all parent nodes. You can then iterate over them and use their `name` attribute.

Comment: BS only returns the first (immediate) parent as the name of the parent and grandparent are the same. It does return two generations of parents if the parent and grandparent are differently named.

Comment: @ManojGovindan That's incorrect. They way your answer is written, maybe, but if you read this answer carefully as described using a loop, it makes sense.